# Compile FLA assets with AS2 actions and ActionScript into SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, intellij-idea, actionscript

I am working on a legacy project that has FLA assets with AS2 actions and some ActionScript code and I have made some changes in the ActionScript code. I want to compile all files into a single SWF. Can you please suggest a possible way of achieving this?

I have tried to compile the entire code in IntelliJ as a Flex Web project. But after compilation the generated SWF does not contain the FLA assets. I did a bit of research and figured out that the FLA's can be imported as SWC library in IntelliJ. But Adobe Flash Pro is not allowing me to export the FLA as SWC since it has AS2 actions.

Answer (score 1):

If you publish the FLA project to an SWF in Adobe Flash Pro the code will be included automatically.

Comment: The actionscript code is not getting included. Is there a way link the AS code to the FLA ?

Comment: My vague memory is that you can use include with the file path. Depending on what your AS files do, I think there's also a primitive version of assigning a base class to the symbol like you can do in AS3.